# Assigning values ​from an input through database lookup

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, search, laravel-scout

First of all, this is a function where I register a client, however, if he is married, I must put the identification of the spouse and with this filling, the function must display the name of the spouse for the user to be sure what he is doing.

husband id finds the husband's name

[image: 1]

I'm using Laravel and this is my form.

```
<div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="cnh">CNH</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cnh" placeholder="0000000000" oninput="mascaracnh(this)">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="Emissor">Emissor</label>
                        <select name="emissorrg" class="form-control">
                            <option selected="" value="">Selecione o Estado (UF)</option>
                            <option value="Acre">Acre</option>
                            <option value="Alagoas">Alagoas</option>
                            <option value="Amapá">Amapá</option>
                            <option value="Amazonas">Amazonas</option>
                            <option value="Bahia">Bahia</option>
                            <option value="Ceará">Ceará</option>
                            <option value="Distrito Federal">Distrito Federal</option>
                            <option value="Espírito Santo">Espírito Santo</option>
                            <option value="Goiás">Goiás</option>
                            <option value="Maranhão">Maranhão</option>
                            <option value="Mato Grosso">Mato Grosso</option>
                            <option value="Mato Grosso do Sul">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
                            <option value="Minas Gerais">Minas Gerais</option>
                            <option value="Pará">Pará</option>
                            <option value="Paraíba">Paraíba</option>
                            <option value="Paraná">Paraná</option>
                            <option value="Pernambuco">Pernambuco</option>
                            <option value="Piauí">Piauí</option>
                            <option value="Rio de Janeiro">Rio de Janeiro</option>
                            <option value="Rio Grande do Sul">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
                            <option value="Rio Grande do Norte">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
                            <option value="Rondônia">Rondônia</option>
                            <option value="Roraima">Roraima</option>
                            <option value="Santa Catarina">Santa Catarina</option>
                            <option value="São Paulo">São Paulo</option>
                            <option value="Sergipe">Sergipe</option>
                            <option value="Tocantins">Tocantins</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="profissao">Profissão</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="profissao"  placeholder="Agricultor, Professor, etc...">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="estadocivil">Estado Civil</label>
                        <select name="estadocivil" class="form-control" id="estadocivil">
                          <option selected="" value="">Selecione</option>
                          <option value="Solteiro">Solteiro</option>
                          <option value="Casado">Casado</option>
                          <option value="Divorciado">Divorciado</option>
                          <option value="União Estável">União Estável</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="conjugecpf">CPF do Cônjuge</label>
                        <input type="text" id="cpfconjuge" class="form-control" name="conjugecpf" disabled>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                <label for="inputCity">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                          <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefone" oninput="mascaratelefone(this)">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                            <label for="inputCEP">Nascimento</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="nascimento">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                          <label for="nomeconjuge">Nome do Cônjuge</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomeconjuge" placeholder="" disabled>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-7">
                      <label for="inputAddress2">Endereço</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endereco" placeholder="Rua dos Bobos, nº 0">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                      <label for="inputAddress2">Foto do Cliente</label>
                      <div class="row col-5">
                        <img id="preview" src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/transparent-designer-must-have-fake-background-39672616.jpg" height="72" width="128">
                    </div>
                      <div class="custom-file" style="margin-top: 5px">
                        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="foto" name="foto">
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Escolha o Arquivo</label>
                        
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    <div class="form-row" style="margin-top: -85px">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <label for="inputCity">Cidade</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cidade">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="inputEstado">Estado</label>
                        <select name="estado" class="form-control">
                            <option selected="" value="">Selecione o Estado (UF)</option>
                            <option value="Acre">Acre</option>
                            <option value="Alagoas">Alagoas</option>
                            <option value="Amapá">Amapá</option>
                            <option value="Amazonas">Amazonas</option>
                            <option value="Bahia">Bahia</option>
                            <option value="Ceará">Ceará</option>
                            <option value="Distrito Federal">Distrito Federal</option>
                            <option value="Espírito Santo">Espírito Santo</option>
                            <option value="Goiás">Goiás</option>
                            <option value="Maranhão">Maranhão</option>
                            <option value="Mato Grosso">Mato Grosso</option>
                            <option value="Mato Grosso do Sul">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
                            <option value="Minas Gerais">Minas Gerais</option>
                            <option value="Pará">Pará</option>
                            <option value="Paraíba">Paraíba</option>
                            <option value="Paraná">Paraná</option>
                            <option value="Pernambuco">Pernambuco</option>
                            <option value="Piauí">Piauí</option>
                            <option value="Rio de Janeiro">Rio de Janeiro</option>
                            <option value="Rio Grande do Sul">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
                            <option value="Rio Grande do Norte">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
                            <option value="Rondônia">Rondônia</option>
                            <option value="Roraima">Roraima</option>
                            <option value="Santa Catarina">Santa Catarina</option>
                            <option value="São Paulo">São Paulo</option>
                            <option value="Sergipe">Sergipe</option>
                            <option value="Tocantins">Tocantins</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label for="inputCEP">CEP</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cep">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
                  </form>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How will I do the search by ID if it is on the same registration form as the customer?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really have an exact question, but I'll help broadly. Basically you've got two things to do:

1. The JS needs to send to the PHP some data and then handle the response
2. The PHP needs to receive the data, search the db, and return what it finds

### Sudo Code (broad strokes)

##### Javascript

> on HusbandIDChange
>
> - Ajax POST/GET with Husband's ID
> - With Return of POST/GET:
>
>   - Fill fields with values

##### PHP

> Get Husband ID Name from Request (POST/GET)
> Do DB query with Husband's ID to get their name
> Pack up Name
> Return to sender

##### Potential JS

```
$("#husband_id").change(function(){
    postingdata = {
        'husband_id': $("#husband_id").html(),
    }
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/php/get_husband_name.php',
        data: postingdata,
        success: function(data){
            d = JSON.parse(data);  
            $('#husband_name').val(d['husband_name'])
            // enable fields or do other things
        },
    });
})
```

##### Potential PHP (really rough, I'm no expert)

```php
$husband_id = $_POST['husband_id'];

$query = 'Select name from spouse_table where id='.$husband_id.';'

// query the db..
$result = do_query($query);

// handle db response
if ($result) {
    // somehow get name from query result
    $husband_name = ?

    // pack data
    echo(json_encode({
        'status':True,
        'husband_name':$husband_name,
        }));
}else{
    // pack error msg
    echo(json_encode({
        'status':False,
        'msg':'No Match was Found!',
        }));
};
```

Comment: How will I do the search by ID if it is on the same registration form as the customer?

Comment: Just post to a different php page. You’ve got 1 php page for the form submit ‘php/register.php’ and then another that ONLY does the search ‘php/spouse_search.php’.